# How to build a sorting algorithm with 2 keys in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I'm aware that Python has a very nice function sorted() for this but I'd like to implement my own function to understand the logic.
**I have a list of strings and I'd like to sort them first by length, then alphabetically.**
For example,

##### Input:

```
['daring','adequate','bold','bait','cold','beautiful']
```

##### Output:

```
['bait','bold','cold','daring','adequate','beautiful']
```

How do I build a function that does this?

I started with building a simple quicksort function for sorting only alphabetically, but now I can't think of a efficient way of progressing from it to include 2 keys at once.
Here is the code: (assumes strings are all in one case)

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <=1:
        return sequence
    else:
        pivot = sequence.pop()

    items_greater = []
    items_lower = []

    for item in sequence:
        if item >pivot:
            items_greater.append(item)

        else:
            items_lower.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_lower) + [pivot] + quick_sort(items_greater)
print(quick_sort(['daring','adequate','bold','bait','cold','beautiful']))
```

TLDR: How to turn this into a Length/Alphebetical sort?
Thanks

Comment: Start by further defining the scope of the problem (for example will you only ever sort lists of words by their length and alphabetical order? Or will you sort numbers by their decimal places and values too?). Then attempt an implementation. If you have questions about implementation come back and ask. // Try starting by sorting as you do now, then calculate the length of the words, then sort that list, then use the result to re-order the sorted word list.

Comment: Seems like the question may start with how to efficiently store two or more store orders for the same list. If the objects in the list are small you could just have different copies of the list. If they are more sizable it might make sense to have a list sorted one way plus a list of references to that list sorted the other. But then you may need to consider what kind of operations or methods you will want to run, for example will you afterward want to remove items from list? Add new items?

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback was my first question asked here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a compare function that compares any two values in the way you define it.

```
def compare(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return len(a) > len(b)
    else:
        return a > b


def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <= 1:
        return sequence
    else:
        pivot = sequence.pop()

    items_greater = []
    items_lower = []

    for item in sequence:
        if compare(item, pivot):
            items_greater.append(item)

        else:
            items_lower.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_lower) + [pivot] + quick_sort(items_greater)


print(quick_sort(['daring', 'adequate', 'bold', 'bait', 'cold', 'beautiful']))
```

this will print

```
['bait', 'bold', 'cold', 'daring', 'adequate', 'beautiful']
```

Comment: thanks that's a simple way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a 'key function' that maps an item into a tuple (item_length, item) prior with pivot in your algorithm. For example:

```
def quick_sort(sequence, key_fn):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <=1:
        return sequence
    else:
        pivot = sequence.pop()

    items_greater = []
    items_lower = []

    for item in sequence:
        if key_fn(item) > key_fn(pivot):
            items_greater.append(item)

        else:
            items_lower.append(item)


    return quick_sort(items_lower, key_fn) + [pivot] + quick_sort(items_greater, key_fn)


print(quick_sort(['daring','adequate','bold','bait','cold','beautiful'], lambda e: (len(e),e)))
```

will return

```
['bait', 'bold', 'cold', 'daring', 'adequate', 'beautiful']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can write it into your quicksort function assuming that you only care about the alphabetical order based on the first letter of each word.

```py
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <=1:
        return sequence
    else:
        pivot = sequence.pop()

    items_greater = []
    items_lower = []

    for item in sequence:
        if item[0] > pivot[0]:
            if item[0] == pivot[0]:
                if len(item) > pivot:
                    items_greater.append(item)
                else:
                    items_lower.append(item)
            items_greater.append(item)

        else:
            items_lower.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_lower) + [pivot] + quick_sort(items_greater)
print(quick_sort(['daring','adequate','bold','bait','cold','beautiful']))
```

returns

```
['adequate', 'bold', 'bait', 'beautiful', 'cold', 'daring']
```